APKO build alpine image cannot render index sbom
I am trying to use chainguard apko to build our own distroless base images, following readme from this repo(https://github.com/chainguard-dev/apko). So I copied yaml definition:
contents:
  repositories:
    - https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
  packages:
    - alpine-base

entrypoint:
  command: /bin/sh -l

# optional environment configuration
environment:
  PATH: /usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin

And tried to run it as docker: docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/work -w /work cgr.dev/chainguard/apko build alpine-base.yaml apko-alpine:test apko-alpine.tar
Unfortunately this did not work with the error

Error: generating index SBOM: generating spdx sbom: unable to render index sbom, no architecture images found
2024/12/30 08:46:09 INFO error during command execution: generating index SBOM: generating spdx sbom: unable to render index sbom, no architecture images found

What can I do?

According to the example on their website you can add "archs":
contents:
  repositories:
    - https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
  packages:
    - alpine-base

entrypoint:
  command: /bin/sh -l

# optional environment configuration
environment:
  PATH: /usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin

archs:
  - x86_64

